# creation of a module with namespace in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, reactjs, typescript

I have a library called, 'myLib' that has several react components, comp1,..,compn, that i want to be able to import to another project.

The folder structure goes as

```
|_Components
       |_ Comp1.js
       |_ Comp2.js
       |_ Comp3.js
|_index.js
```

Currently inside the index.js i have

```
exports.Comp1 = require('./components/comp1');
exports.Comp2 = require('./components/comp2');
exports.Comp3 = require('./components/comp3');
```

And inside the project i'm importing 'myLib', i'm doing so by

```
import myLib = require('myLib');
```

and to use the react components 'Comp1', inside the 'myApp' 's render(), i do

```
<myLib.Comp1></myLib.Comp1>
```

But i'm getting this error

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner can have refs. This usually means that you're trying to add a ref to a component that doesn't have an owner (that is, was not created inside of another component's `render` method). Try rendering this component inside of a new top-level component which will hold the ref.
```

A little bit of googling suggest react is being referenced twice. Once inside the Comp1 and the 2nd time inside 'myApp' who's using Comp1.

My question is, am i doing this right? and how to fix the error i'm getting.

**Edit:**

After reading the bundle.js that comes from 'myApp' it does seem like react is being referenced twice.  My question now is how do i get rid of it.  I'm using browserify.

Answer (score 1):

> My question now is how do i get rid of it. I'm using browserify.

From : https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/two-weird-tricks-that-fix-react-7cf9bbdef375

---

Here’s just a few ways why this might have happened:

- You installed a package that specifies React as a dependency, and later installed React;
- You installed React, and later a package that specifies a different version of React as a dependency;
- You’re using a global React you get from CDN, but installed a library from NPM that got its own copy of React;
- You ran npm install inside some NPM dependency’s folder, thus installing its development dependencies that likely include React;

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by bundling my dependencies into a separate bundle stated here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29011560/2149419